# How to scroll multiple component together in UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uipickerview

I have a problem related to scrolling multiple components of UIPickerView.
I created uipickerview with two components but when i scroll one of them, other also scroll but after part of second.

Code :

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
       return [finalArray count];
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
if (component == 0) {
    return [[finalArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"value1"];
}else if (component == 1){
    return [[finalArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"value2"];
}else{
    return nil;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        [thePickerView selectRow:row inComponent:0 animated:NO];
        [thePickerView selectRow:row inComponent:1 animated:NO];
}
```

What i want is scrolling any components should scroll all together just like it is only one.
It should not show even part of second for auto scrolling.

If it is possible, what do you recommend to do?...

Comment: If you want both to scroll together, what is the purpose of making two components?

Comment: For making better alignment..
I have tried with one component but i didn't get the way to put multiple lables in a row with better alignment..
i want effect like when pickerview have more component..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oke I got the solution with comment of [Anupdas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767730/anupdas) ...

By giving number of spaces i get solution to my problem.

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithString:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"value1"]];
    lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"                                            "];
    lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:[[finalArray objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"value2"]];
    return lbl1;
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that you found a solution. You can also use `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` If you want to customize further.

Comment: Your solution work correctly only if you use a fixed space font like Courier. If you use Arial, the space between the string in the same row may changes

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 or more different labels for the same component using the view in the argument: in this example I create 2 labels (labelName and lableValue) and I assign different positions and sizes (fixed), and different fonts.

```
//Update view for each row
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel* labelName;
    UILabel* labelValue;

    UIView* container;
    UIFont *font1 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:19.0f];
    UIFont *font2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0f];

    if(view==nil)
    {
        //Define the container for the 2 lables (or more)
        container = [[UIView alloc] init];

        //Create the new labels defining position and size
        labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2 , 250, 20)];
        labelValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 2 , 90, 20)];

        //Add the labels to the container
        [container addSubview:labelName];
        [container addSubview:labelValue];

        //Customize the font for the lables
        labelName.font = font1;
        labelValue.font = font2;

        //To show the label frame (just to test the position and size, change the backcolor)
        labelName.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        labelValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
```

After this code, you can check the row and column to assign the string to the labels. With this code you can put in the same space two or more strings without take care about font size (problem that you have if you concatenate 2 strings and don't use a fixed font)